# How add to button second function on click, when was map and render ?(react)

Tags: reactjs, function, button

How to add second function onClick, when was map and render i need to add class change on all buttons to make them dynamic look

````
  function ButtonsDes({button, filter}) {
    
    return (
        <div className="planet__btn">
            {
                button.map((e, i)=>{
                    return <button   type="button" onClick={() =>filter(e)} key={i}>{e}</button>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default ButtonsDes;```
````

Comment: You want to add `onClick` which should be different for each and every button rendered through `map` ?

Comment: i want to add second function to all buttons not only filter but filter and  handleclick who change the className when was button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend if you want the function to be dynamic, is to pass dynamic value, Also you are doing in the right way, just you need to understand, let me give you an example.

```
  function ButtonsDes({button, filter}) {
    // button value is like button= ['green', 'blue', 'yellow']
    
    return (
        <div className="planet__btn">
            {
                button.map((color, i)=>{
                    return <button   type="button" onClick={() =>filter(color)} key={i}>{color}</button>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default ButtonsDes;
```

Here when a html button is generated the filter function will get different color, on your filter color you can check for filter value and have different logic based on that, possible implementation for filter function

```
function filter(color) {
  if (color === 'red') {
   // your custom logic goes here
  } else if (color === 'green') {
    // your custom logic when color is green.
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to apply two function on a button click at the same time, then you can do like this

`<button type="button" key={i} onClick={() => { function1(); function2();}}>{e}</button>`

or you can create wrapper function, something like this

```
wrapperFunction = () => {
    //do something
    function1();
    //do something
    function2();
}
```

These functions can be defined as a method on the parent class and then called from the wrapper function.

`onClick={wrapperFunction}`

Comment: Yes, we can also use `async and await` if `function2` depends on `functions1`